# How to create a page that shows cursor position of all users connected? Node.js, ws, express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ws

I want to create a simple page where I would display mouse coordinates of all the users connected.

I got as far as showing mouse coordinates of a single connected client. Sending the mouse coordinates to the server. Sending the data back.
I don't know where to go from here. I'm thinking of how to save every response from the server as an object and then display that object. I'm stuck and don't know of a proper way to solve this assignment.

Server side code.

```
var express = require('express')
var WebSocket = require('ws')
var app = express()

app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log("Server started on port 3000")
})
app.use(express.static('public'))

var server = new WebSocket.Server({port: 3200})
server.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log("Connected, using WebSocket")
    console.log(server.clients.size)

    socket.on('message', function(msg) {
        server.clients.forEach(function each(client) {
            client.send(msg)
        })
    })
})
```

Client side.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app" v-on:mousemove="clientCoords">
        <p>{{displayX}}</p>
        <p>{{displayY}}</p>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

    <script>
        var app = new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data() {
                return {
                    clientInformation: {}
                    ,
                    clientList: [

                    ],
                    clientCoord: {},
                    displayX: '',
                    displayY: '',
                    socket: new WebSocket('ws://localhost:3200')
                }
            },
            methods:{
                clientCoords(e){
                    this.clientInformation.coordX = e.clientX
                    this.clientInformation.coordY = e.clientY
                    this.socket.send(JSON.stringify(this.clientInformation))
                }
            },
            mounted() {
                this.clientList.push(this.clientInformation)
                this.socket.addEventListener('message', (msg) => {
                    this.displayX = JSON.parse(msg.data).coordX
                    this.displayY = JSON.parse(msg.data).coordY
                })
            }
        })
    </script>
    <style>
        #app {
            height: 100%;
        }
        body {
            height: 100%;
        }
        html {
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should send coordinates from all the clients via socket, and emit the coordinates to all the users you're currently connected to. This won't show a newly connected user the coordinates of someone else's mouse, bus as soon as others move their mouse, their coordinates will show up

Comment: Think of it like a chat; your client-side app has to know *who* has said something; the way to do this is to add the socket.id to the message you send. Your client side has to keep track of the separate positions in a suitable data structure (like an object, with ID as key) to be able to display them all.

Comment: I think that I should create an object for every connected client and display them as separate objects as @Chris G suggested. I'm hoping that someone helps me find a solution.